# Invalid Pattern matching in FindMatchingFiles workflow in MSBuild

Tags: xaml, msbuild, build-process, workflow-activity

I'm customizing the default template in TFS build to accommodate my solution. In the FindMatchingFiles workflow - MatchPattern property I'm trying to set Path.IO.Combine. My solution file is in a folder and the files I'm trying to match are one folder up in the Applications folder. The following pattern doesn't yeild results although there are files.

```
IO.Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(localProject), "..\..\Applications\Windows Services\**\*.csproj")
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain in greater detail what you are doing. statements about customizing the 'default template in TFS' just sound like something you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: I have read a lot of articles for TFS builds where customizing the Default Template provided is pretty common. I'm trying to copy builds from one folder to another folder and setting path for that purpose.